# CherryPy & php: can't load class of data from pickle, but works from ssh on server

Tags: php, json, class, pickle, cherrypy

I am using CherryPy to generate and parse data for a php webpage, but getting an error that I can't replicate locally or via SSH (logging into the server and running the python script from the prompt works okay).

The current sticky error message is:

```
File "modules/flex.py", line 335, in convert
    ref_data = cPickle.load(f2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Data'
```

Another pickle loads fine in a previous line, and both pickles represent class objects with a variety of dictionaries and lists of lists. But one of these works, and the other doesn't.

In general with CherryPy, what's the best way to isolate error messages? I can run the /cp/ function from it's URL, and I can look at the webserver error log, but even these two don't always give an error message (or the correct error).

On the other side, in php, I am using this code to retrieve a json object representing a python list of lists:

```
$obj = file_get_contents($senddata);
$sue = json_decode($obj);
```

Is that an acceptable method? What's the best way to pass and generate php arrays from python data structures?

Comment: Currently bypassing this problem by building a MySQL table and pulling data that way, but I still want to know why the pickle isn't working. I can't just build a table every time I want to do this!

Comment: Now I'm certain that I can't save and load a CLASS full of data on this server, but I can do it on my local machine or when running the python script from SSH prompt. However, if I save a dictionary of dictionaries in a pickle, it works okay. Is this a cherrypy bug or intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have different issues:

1. Your code is not working because the PYTHONPATH (`sys.path`) are not the same
   in your python interpreter, when you are connected trough ssh and in the python
   that is running to serve the webapp. I say that because you are tying to deserialize
   the data from a module, which it does exists (otherwise will be `ImportError`)
   but do not have the `class` declaration of `Data`, probably a file with the same
   name as that module is in the same directory and trying to find the `class Data`
   in that file. When you serialize you don't save the class declaration, just how to 
   reconstruct that object.
2. What do you mean with "the correct error"?, when the environment
   is "production", CherryPy by default log the traceback of the last error,
   you can of course change the default behavior with [custom error handling](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cperror.html).
3. You should stick with JSON for communication betweeen languages, is pretty standard
   and efficient to be parsed in both sides.

I hope that helps.

Comment: So if I get you correctly: If Data refers to a pickled class instance, rather than the class object, it won't unpickle correctly?

Comment: By "the correct error" - I mean that the error messages offer useful information about where to look for a bug. In this case, I didn't understand what the error was indicating.

Comment: This was saving a local (same server) data set as a pickle. I think I rewrote it to save as JSON and the error was resolved - as you noted.